# How to check if enum value exists with C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, enums, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have following problem

Lets assume there is a library that have two versions

Version 1 have declared enum such as this

```
enum colors {
RED,
GREEN,
BLUE
}
```

Version 2 looks like this

```
enum colors {
RED,
GREEN,
BLUE,
TURQUOISE
}
```

What I would like to do is to perform compile time check with preprocessor as to which enum value I can use, which would look something like this

```
#include <colors_library.h>

int main()
{

#if TURQUOISE

some_function(TURQUOISE);

#else

some_function(BLUE);

#endif
}
```

But so far I no success making it work with neither #if and #ifdef directives

Comment: You are asking the preprocessor to check information it is not privy to. Not sure there's a way even in later translation steps.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. The preprocessing pass happens before the C++ code gets interpreted in any way, whatsoever. Instead of C++ code the file can contain the combined contents of all Harry Potter novels, and the preprocessor won't care. What you can do, though, is use several features of the current C++ standard, together with templates, in order to achieve the exact same thing. See your C++ textbook, that covers the current C++ standard, for more information.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't do that.  Essentially, the preprocessor works with definitions, checks, and expansions of text macros (i.e. it is a glorified form of text substitution).   `enum` values are handled by a later phase of translation, after the preprocessor is done.

Comment: You could instrument your build perhaps, to inspect library versions and inject preprocessor directives to inform you of the version. But that is another question, needing more details.

Comment: You might want to explain why you want to have two versions of an `enum colors` in the same program.    When I think about it, I suspect it would actually break the one-definition rule.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to have a version #define in your headers, anyway:

`colors_library.h`

```
#define COLOR_VERSION 2
enum colors 
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    TURQUOISE
}
```

Then,

```
#if COLOR_VERSION == 2
some_function(TURQUOISE);
#else
some_function(BLUE);
#endif
```

that way, you maintain modern functionality (enums, type-safety, etc...) for everything except the compile-time checks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the decision with the preprocessor, you could achieve something similar using the library [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum). Specifically, you can check for the existence of a value in an enum with `magic_enum::enum_contains`:

```
if constexpr (magic_enum::enum_contains<colors>("TURQUOISE")) {
    some_function(*magic_enum::enum_cast<colors>("TURQUOISE"));
}
else {
    some_function(colors::BLUE);
}
```